# JQuery Ajax Not Sending Data to Php File or Running Success Function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am having a problem with the jQuery Ajax function not sending the data to the corresponding php file, and then not running the success function. Here is my js:

```
function meetMember(empl_id) {

var member = {id: empl_id}

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'php/infocheck.php', 
    data: member, 
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        alert('hi');
        console.log(data);
        $('#member-info').append(data); 
    }   
});
}
```

And the infocheck.php code:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

include('db-info.php');

$id = $_POST['id'];

    $q = "SELECT * FROM team WHERE empl_id = $id LIMIT 1";
    $member = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($q));
    $met = $member['ifmet'];

    if($met != 1) {
        mysql_query("UPDATE team SET ifmet = 1 WHERE empl_id = $id");
    }

    echo "<img src=\"game/images/{$member['image']}\" alt='' style='padding:2px 10px 0px 0px; float:left;' />";
    echo "<h3>{$member['name']}</h3>";
    echo "<h4><em>{$member['title']}</em><h4>";
    echo "<p>{$member['description']}</p>";

?>
```

When I view the php file in the browser, I get the errors:

"Notice: Undefined index: id in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Development/ETL24/php/infocheck.php on line 8

Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Development/ETL24/php/infocheck.php on line 12"

The console.log and alert in the success function do not run. I do not even get the echo in the console when I view the php file. Please let me know of any ideas or questions you might have. Thank you.

Comment: did you checked for id in your php file?is it a valid number?

Comment: it seems that an exception occurred in your php file that prevent returning result for ajax call , and results in not calling success function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dataType: 'html'`  your file return `HTML`

When your open the file on browser(`GET`) yes you get a **Error** because it need to pass the `id` by  `POST`.

if you want to debug it change to `type: GET` and on the url append `?id=1`

Comment: `var member = {id: empl_id}` need to end line with `;`

Answer (score 0):

Change the line

```
var member = {id: empl_id}
```

to

```
var member = "id="+empl_id;
```

or

```
  var member = {"id": empl_id}
```

Comment: Let me know if it works. I really don't understand the reason for downvote.

Comment: +1 for being sorry about not seeing your edition before my post

Comment: :-) Thanks !! Appreciate that !!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, mysql functions are not maintained anymore, consider to change to mysqli functions.

this piece of code:

```
var member = {id: empl_id}
```

should be written

```
var member = {"id": empl_id}; // notice the semi-colon too
```

Since you are not passing and "id" parameter, your $id variable is null because $_POST['id'] is actually empty. This explains this warning:

```
Notice: Undefined index: id in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Development/ETL24/php/infocheck.php on line 8
```

You are actually setting $id to null.

And such, your query is turning to be something like

```
SELECT * FROM team WHERE empl_id = LIMIT 1
```

Which then make your mysql_query to return false instead of resource, this is what this error means:

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Development/ETL24/php/infocheck.php on line 12"
```

In abstract, just change your variable to JSON and begin use the mysqli functions

Comment: Sorry @AbhishekSaha Saha, I've started writing before the edit you made in the third line

Comment: No offence..I accept that and your answer is more descriptive.

Comment: `{"id": empl_id}` and `{id: empl_id}` no difference, works anyway

Comment: Without "" around id makes id a variable.

Comment: @AbhishekSaha nop ,try it is a object attribute

Comment: I Apologize for my ignorance. Learnt !